# Loop Through List of Dict of Lists in Python and Django

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset that returns a result like below:

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>,
    {
        123: 
            [
                {'field1': 123, 'field2': 'August', 'field3': 50},
                {'field1': 123, 'field2': 'September', 'field3': 25},
                {'field1': 123, 'field2': 'October', 'field3': 70}
            ],
        789: 
            [
                {'field1': 789, 'field2': 'August', 'field3': 80},
                {'field1': 789, 'field2': 'September', 'field3': 22},
                {'field1': 789, 'field2': 'October', 'field3': 456}
            ],
    })
```

I'm trying to loop through the list in a template, but I can only get the key to show, such that:

```
        {% for each in results %}
            {{ each }}<br>
        {% endfor %}
```

Returns:

```
123
789
```

I've tried looping through `results.items`, and it returns nothing. I've tried using `key, value`, which also returns nothing. I initially thought I'd be able to have a nested `for loop`, and loop through `each`:

```
        {% for each in results %}
            {% for row in each %}
                {{ row }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

But that returns `'int' object is not iterable`

I'm not sure what I'm missing, if anyone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are, indeed, trying to iterate through an integer.

The first for loop, iterates through `results.keys()`, that's why you get back those integers which are keys in your first dictionary.

Something like this would work in python:

```
for x in results:
    for y in results[x]:
        print y
```

Or, you can use .items() / .iteritems() like this:

```
for k, v in results.items():
    for small_dict in v:
        print small_dict
```

Considering that you're trying to do this in a Django template, I think that the first solution would work for you.

Comment: Thank you! Part of the problem was that I was initializing `results` by doing `results = defaultdict(list)`, but doing `results = {}` worked with `results.items`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't seen this syntax for Python. I haven't worked with django. So, I will just use your own format, and modify just one thing. Instead of saying `for row in each`, you should use `for row in results[each]`. `results` is a dictionary, and `each` is a key. If you want the value of that dictionary for that key, you need to get it by `results[each]`. Now you can loop through the value if it is iterable.

```
    {% for each in results %}
        {% for row in results[each] %}
            {{ row }}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `values` method of a dict to obtain each sublist, which you can then iterate over in a nested loop:

```
{% for each in results.values %}
    {% for row in each %}
        {{ row.field1 }}
        {{ row.field2 }}
        {{ row.field3 }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```